# Can someone explain why a "+" is needed before closing quotes in an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, string-concatenation

I am pretty new to Javascript and this is the first time I have come across this type of concatenation while taking a JQuery course. My question is regarding the + sign and why it is needed with all the quotes before the ">" to close the HTML tag. In other words the + "'> " part of the code. Why can't you just end the quotes and close the tag without a plus sign? Can someone break that down step by step? I left a comment in the script where I am confused. There are 2 instances. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("document").ready(function() {    
        buildBookmarks('h3', 'header'); 
    }); 

    function buildBookmarks(strWhichTag, sBookMarkNode) {

        var cAnchorCount = 0;

        var oList = $("<ul id='bookmarksList'>");

        $("div:not([id=header]) " + strWhichTag).each(function() { //This is the part 
            $(this).html("<a name='bookmark" + cAnchorCount + "'></a>" + $(this).html());       
            oList.append($("<li><a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> " + $(this).text() + "</a></li>"));
        });

        $("#" + sBookMarkNode).append(oList);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: because... string concatenation?

Comment: Funny enough, Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting can help you make some sense of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already ended the string literal, back here:

```
"<li><a href='#bookmark"
//                     ^ here
```

Now you’re concatenating an expression to the string before it, and concatenating the result of that concatenation with another string literal, and concatenation is done with the `+` operator.

If we replace the literals with placeholders representing expressions (which they are), and add parentheses, it might become clearer:

```
oList.append($(A + (cAnchorCount++) + B + ($(this).text()) + C));
```

Note that the HTML here isn’t special in any way; the strings you have here are strings like any other. They just happen to represent HTML. (I’d recommend learning the W3C DOM before jQuery, by the way; it makes this separation clearer.)

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm confused on the quotation placement and why it cannot look like this: "<li><a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++' + ">" -OR- "<a name='bookmark" + cAnchorCount + '> + "</a>"

Comment: Thank you! I was failing to understand that the single quotation ' was actually part of the string itself! I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

The script is building an HTML element in Javascript by concatenating strings together. You can think of it this way:

```
tag_opening + anchor_count + tag_closing
```

The `+` is necessary because it’s adding strings together. Without it, you would just be following one string with another, which would result in a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that now that it's 3 pieces. I think I'm confused on the quotation placement and why it cannot look like this: "<li><a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++' + ">"

Comment: Why `++`? The second `'` needs to go inside the `""` because it closes the `href` attribute value inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The plus here is used for concatenation. What you're really doing is adding a string which you've written (a name='bookmark) plus a variable (cAnchorCount), plus another string ('>) to make one long string. Without the plus, the syntax makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is unclear, but you are combining a variable an an HTML string:

```
"<a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> "
```

Will evaluate to something like:

```
<a href='#bookmark1'>
```

---

The code you listed uses external double quote (`"`) to wrap the string and internal single quotes (`'`) to wrap the attribute values.  There is no interpolation in JavaScript strings, only string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

They are trying to format a string so that once the code compiles, it will be readable HTML.

For example:

`oList.append($("<li><a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'> " + $(this).text() + "</a></li>"));` is trying to ultimately get

`<li><a href='#bookmark3'>TEXT</a></li>`

You need the `'>` to close the tag properly from `<a href='` after adding in text.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it has nothing to do with HTML or the content of the strings being concatenated, it's just that JavaScript uses the `+` operator to concatenate strings.  I imagine every language uses *some* operator to do this.  For example:

```
var result = 'first string' + 'second string';
```

This creates the concatenated string:

```
'first stringsecond string'
```

Now if one of those strings happens to be a variable, the same thing happens:

```
var someVariable = 'second string';
var result = 'first string' + someVariable;
```

This still results in the same concatenated string:

```
'first stringsecond string'
```

That's all the code in the question is doing in these cases.  Concatenating one string to another.  For example:

```
$("div:not([id=header]) " + strWhichTag)
```

The variable `strWhichTag` contains some string value, likely the name of an HTML tag judging by its name and usage.  So if it contains something like `'div'` then the result is:

```
$("div:not([id=header]) div")
```

This overall resulting string is then being evaluated by jQuery as a selector to identify a set of HTML elements on which to operate.  But the string concatenation doesn't matter, it could just as easily result in this:

```
$("div:not([id=header]) some nonsense")
```

if the `strWhichTag` variable contained the value `'some nonsense'`.

Answer (score 0):

THis is called concatenation, the # which is the ID of the string, while the sBookMarkNode is the variable.  Then when the page loads it will append (create)  right after the # + sBookMarkNode which the variable sBookMarkNode is created apparently else where or is a global variable since I cannot see it in your code snippet.